# My magic_quotes_gpc is on but my script won't proceed telling me it's off

Tags: php, magic-quotes-gpc

My magic_quotes_gpc is on but my script won't proceed telling me it's off.  I even created a php.ini file and specifically entered

magic_quotes_gpc = On

I uploaded a phpinfo.php file and I in deed do not see where "magic quotes" is even present.

http://domainswebhostingecommerce.com/phpinfo.php

You can go to the root domain of this url and see the error I'm receiving.  Does anyone know of a solution?

Thanks
William Cornett, MBA, PMP, FFL

Comment: Why do you intentionally make your life harder? Thanks Ivan K, Just a CAT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your php version is 5.4. Magic quotes are removed now.

http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

And you have no reason to use them!

Comment: And not soon enough it was.